# Unable to extract title from feed in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, rss

I am trying to extract data from [this feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/ebaumsworld/aUjW). This is my code:

```
$xml = file_get_contents_curl($feed_url);
$rss  = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($xml);
```

The function `file_get_contents_curl` get the data from webpage. On dumping it in a var like this:

```
var_dump($xml);
```

It echoes everything as expected ( i mean all the title, link etc. tags). However, if I use `var_dump` on `$rss`:

```
var_dump($rss);
```

I get this reponse:

```
object(DOMDocument)#1 (34) { ["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["documentElement"]=> NULL ["actualEncoding"]=> NULL ["encoding"]=> NULL ["xmlEncoding"]=> NULL ["standalone"]=> bool(true) ["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true) ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" 
["xmlVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true) ["documentURI"]=> NULL ["config"]=> NULL ["formatOutput"]=> bool(false) ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false) ["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false) ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true) 
["recover"]=> bool(false) ["substituteEntities"]=> bool(false) ["nodeName"]=> string(9) "#document" ["nodeValue"]=> NULL ["nodeType"]=> int(9) ["parentNode"]=> NULL ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> NULL 
["lastChild"]=> NULL ["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> NULL ["ownerDocument"]=> NULL ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> NULL ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Now, I can't extract title or anything else from the feed. My code is like this:

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
  $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

The feed, however, has an error if you open it up in chrome `error on line 273 at column 11: Encoding error` but it opens in Firefox. But I guess I should be able to parse the feed up to first point of error.

Here is a sample of the feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <title>eBaum's World - Featured Media</title>
    <link>http://www.ebaumsworld.com</link>
    <atom:link href="http://www.ebaumsworld.com/rss/featured/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <description>The latest featured media</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <copyright>eBaum's World (c) 1998-2015</copyright>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 25 Nov 2015 03:31:12 -0500</lastBuildDate>
    <pubDate>Wed, 25 Nov 2015 03:31:12 -0500</pubDate>
            <item>
        <title>24 People Being Complete A$$holes</title>
        <link>http://www.ebaumsworld.com/pictures/view/84832600/</link>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="120">
                        <a href="http://www.ebaumsworld.com/pictures/view/84832600/"><img width="320" height="220" src="http://cdn.ebaumsworld.com/thumbs/2015/11/24/070634/84832600/assholes.jpg" border="0" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        People acting like such mega-jerks it might send you into a blind rage!                     </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            ]]>
        </description>
        <pubDate>Tue, 24 Nov 2015 23:02:00 -0500</pubDate>
        <enclosure type="image/jpg" url="http://cdn.ebaumsworld.com/thumbs/2015/11/24/070634/84832600/assholes.jpg" length="10000"/>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.ebaumsworld.com/pictures/view/84832600/</guid>
    </item>
```

This is my function definition for `file_get_contents_curl`:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
  $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: can you edit your question to include a sample of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SimpleXMLElement` and access the `xml` nodes.

```
$xml = file_get_contents_curl($feed_url);
$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($x as $node) {
  print $node->title . PHP_EOL;
  print $node->description . PHP_EOL;
}
```

will output

```
eBaum's World - Featured Media
The latest featured media
```

Comment: post the link to the rss or full xml string to pastebin or something similar, you should update your question to include the function definition of `file_get_contents_curl`

Comment: clicking on the link in this feed will take you to the feed. Here is the link in plain text `http://feeds.feedburner.com/ebaumsworld/aUjW`. I will update the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With your url to the actual XML feed, you can simply load it via `simplexml_load_file()`:

```
<?php
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
$url = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/ebaumsworld/aUjW":
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
    echo $item->title;
// possible output:24 People Being Complete A$$holes
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($xml)` gives me `bool(false)`.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: Did you read my comment? Your XML was corrupted and needed to bo corrected (adding channel and rss, that is). It works for me on [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org) (copy the whole answer and check if you want).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did read that comment but I just posted part of the feed and not complete feed it would be too big. Here is a link to complete feed `http://feeds.feedburner.com/ebaumsworld/aUjW`.